# QuoteLine Item Standard object "Discount"

Tags: workflow, quotelineitem

**Scenario** : If Check box field "Referencing Pricing" is true then set discount 100 % .

I created a workflow and set the value for discount as 100.

But when i am testing this functionality and check the "Referencing Pricing" so i am getting an error on discount field :**Error: Discount must be between 0 and 100**

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value to 1, not 100. This is because internally, percentages are expressed as being a decimal percentage. This is what allows you to write Discount * UnitPrice, for example, to display a discounted price. To figure out what value to use, you simply take your percentage value and divide by 100. For example, 50%, as a formula, is written as 0.50.